# Keep getting 'wrong code' with Deezer oauth and Parse.com via cloud httpRequest (code is OK via PostMan)

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, deezer

I'm setting up the server side of my authentication flow with Deezer. I get an authentication code client side, and then, server side I try to convert it into a token (http://developers.deezer.com/api/oauth).

I have no issue client side, the issue is server side (Parse.com via Cloud code).

I'm doing a request like that:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/access_token',
    params: {
        app_id: DEEZER_APP_ID,
        secret: DEEZER_APP_SECRET,
        code: request.params.code
    }
}).then(function (httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse.text);
});
```

note: I'm not looking for the error callback because Deezer always respond a 200 (...).

I keep getting a 'wrong code' response by deezer api. When I use the exact same code with Postman (I'm trying the code on Postman AFTER the request on Parse, the code is only valid once), I successfully retrieve the access token.

I'm now using an other nodejs backend (not on Parse) to act like a proxy for this request:

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/access_token',
    qs: {
        app_id: req.query.app_id,
        secret: req.query.secret,
        code: req.query.code
    }
};
request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
    res.respond(body);
});
```

And it works perfectly. But I really don't want to maintains 2 backends for 1 application.

Am I doing something wrong ? Does Parse.com via httpRequest manipulate the query in a special way that deezer api does not understand (but my other backend has no problems with it) ?

UPDATE:

As asked in the comment I'm getting the code this way (Cordova mobile app):

```
var redirect_uri = "http://myredirecturi.com/callback";
var scope = "basic_access,email,offline_access";
var app_id = DEEZER_APP_ID;
var ref = window.open('https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=' + app_id + '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri) + '&response_type=code&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scope), '_blank', 'location=no');
```

When the callback is triggered:

```
var code = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
Parse.Cloud.run('deezerAuth', {
    code: code
}).then(function (result) {

});
```

Comment: Have you verified that `request.params.code` actually contains a value and is not null or empty?

Comment: Yes I have, I log the code and use it with Postman

Comment: Can you give us more details on how you obtain the code? The error message happens when the code expired or the linked user is no more recognized.

Comment: @Fred_Dzr I'm 100% sure the code is valid. Before doing the httpRequest I log it. The httpRequest send me back  'wrong code', then I use it with Postman, the exact same code, and I successfully get an acces_token. I try with Postman AFTER the httpRequest on Parse failed. Also when I use the same flow to pass it to my other backend it works without problem.

Comment: @Fred_Dzr I have updated my answer as asked

Comment: Just one thing I was thinking about, why do you implement the both sides? a DZ.login() should be enough normally, cf http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/login?

Comment: @Fred_Dzr I'm doing a mobile application with the Ionic Framework, so I don't have a valid redirect uri to provide. When I try with localhost (provided in my app params too) after I provide the credential it never come back to my application and I just have a 'Load Error'. With my own flow I managed to intercept the callback call after the user as provided is credential and then finish the process server side.